# Cosine Periodicity

Tags: trigonometry

At what $\varphi$ does this functional value repeat its self?

$$ x(t)=\cos(2\pi t\omega)=\cos(2\pi t\omega +\varphi)$$

I want the smallest $\varphi$ such that the cycle exactly repeats itself.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: This is no different than the periodicity of $\cos(x)$.

Comment: Can you calculate the period of $ cos(2\pi t\omega)$?

Comment: hi thank you for responding. I am aware. The problem is I noticed that for very high frequenies (cycle repeats many times) i didnt need to go to $2\pi$ to get one full overlap of the wave on top of itself. So yes $2\pi$ will do it, but it seems like its not the smallest value to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The period of $\cos x$ is $2\pi k$, where $k$ is an integer.
Since there is no defined $t$ or $\omega$, the period of $\cos (2\pi t \omega)$ would be $\boxed{2\pi}$

Comment: thank you for responding. However is $2\pi$ the absolute smallest number? Because for high frequencies, it does not seem like I need to go all the way to $2\pi$ get one full  repeat. I feel like the smallest $\phi$ should be somewhat proportional to how fast it cycles.

Comment: $\omega$ is just a paramater. How does $\phi$ adjust with $t\omega$ ?

Comment: Edit: the period would be $\frac{2\pi}{t\omega}$

Answer (score 1):

The period of $x(t) = \cos t$ is $2\pi$.  To find the period $\varphi$ of $x(t) = \cos(2\pi\omega t)$, set $2\pi\omega\varphi = 2\pi$, then solve for $\varphi$.

> $$\varphi = \frac{2\pi}{2\pi\omega} = \frac{1}{\omega}$$